# AAD Authentication issue with custom redirectUrl

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, owin, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I have an ASP.Net MVC Application, and I'm using Azure Active Directory authentication (owin authentication) as well.

I have my site URL is 'http://example.com' and my tenant has been configured with redirect url to 'http://www.example.com'.

```
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = Authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = "http://www.example.com",
                RedirectUri = "http://www.example.com",

                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                    {
                        var code = context.Code;
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            });
```

When I try with this configuration I get user claims under 'AuthorizationCodeReceived' event but this event is being called multiple times until AAD error throws. I don't get any error while debugging my application except AAD error page. 
I don't understand what is the problem here, same configuration was working with WSFederation identity authentication mechanism.

How can I achieve that? Because I am forced to post authentication redirect them to 'www.example.com' doesn't matter they came either.

---

Note: I had tried with redirect url 'example.com', and it works. However, I am curious to know what is happening with above setup?

1. example.com (Site URL) --> example.com (AAD RedirectURL) = Works
2. www.example.com (Site URL) -->  www.example.com (AAD RedirectURL) = Works
3. example.com (Site URL) -->  www.example.com (AAD RedirectURL) = Doesn't Work

Solution: Use dynamic URL based on the URL whatever users enter,

```
RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
                    {
                        string appBaseUrl = context.Request.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.PathBase;
                        context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = appBaseUrl;
                        context.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = appBaseUrl;
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
```

Answer (score 0):

When we integrate Azure Active Directory with [OAuth 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code) or [OpenId connect protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-protocols-openid-connect-code), we can send the **redirect_uri** parameter to Azure Active Directory. And the Azure Active Directory will verify it with the values you register on the portal. This parameter is **recomend** for the **authorization endpoint**, that means it also works without this parameter when the application only have the unique **redirect_uri**.

And only when the value matches with values register on the portal if we send this parameter, the Azure Active Directory send the correct response to the **redirect_uri** or it would send the error message like `The reply address '...' does not match the reply addresses configured for the application`. You can capture the request and response using **Fiddler** to get the detail error message that Azure Active Directory returns.

In this scenario, that your application have different domains. We need to register all of them on the portal and to specify the domain the current application using dynamically as you mentioned.

### Update

1. publish the web app to Azure, then we can visit the web app by the default domain(A) provide by Azure
2. add the custom domain(B) for this web app
3. modify the redrect_uri from A to B
4. visit the web app with domain A
5. login the web app from Azure AD
6. redirect the web app to domain B with the user sign-in successfully

Comment: I might have missed the point to mentioned here that I have already registered both the URLs under azure portal (my tenant). However, it doesn't work if I try to access the site with url (example.com) and expecting return on site url (www.examle.com).
Also I don't get exception which says 'The reply address '...' does not match the reply addresses configured for the application.'. Since my both the URLs are registered.

Comment: Did you config the domain www.example.com and example.com to the same web server? If I understood correctly, it should also work for this scenario.

Comment: Yes, I have both the URLs on the same web server. I agree with you but it doesn't work, I tried with sample application too.

Comment: Based on the test, it works well for me. I would update the steps in the post. Please let me whether it is helpful.